# Почему векторное изображение в андроид ниже пятой версии становится черным?

Tags: android, vector

Использую в своем проекте векторную графику из-за удобства, и при тесте на андроид от 5ой версии все отображается как надо, а на андроид ниже пятой версии векторное изображение принимает черный цвет вместо нужного установленного в xml. Независимо от того где это изображение установлено, будто кнопка или `ImageView`

Comment: Попробуй android:layerType="software" для imageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для полноценной работы с векторной графикой в версиях до 5.0, нужно использовать библиотеку поддержки, начиная с 23.2.1 .

Подключите ее через gradle.

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
```

А вот [ссылка](https://github.com/liaohuqiu/android-support-23.2-sample) на официальный пример от разработчиков этой библиотеки. Воспользуйтесь их примером.